# Калькулятор

Tags: awt, java, события, swing, калькулятор

Доброго времени суток.
Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно реализовать действие для кнопок "sqrt"(вычисление квадратного корня), "pow(x,2)"(вторая степень), "c"(общий сброс) и "<"(удаление последнего символа). Дело в том, что сразу после вычисления квадратного корня получившийся результат не возводится в степень, а после общего сброса бывает вообще неразбериха.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyCalc extends JFrame {
private JButton display;
private double result;
private String lastCom;
private boolean start;

private void addButton(String name, ActionListener listener, int x, int y,
        int width, int height) {
    JButton button = new JButton(name);
    button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    getContentPane().add(button);
}

public MyCalc() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Мой калькулятор");
    setBounds(200, 200, 203, 242);
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));

    ActionListener output = new OutputAction();
    ActionListener command = new CommandAction();

    result = 0;
    lastCom = "=";
    start = true;

    display = new JButton("0");
    display.setEnabled(false);
    getContentPane().add(display);
    display.setBounds(5, 10, 177, 30);

    addButton("7", output, 5, 50, 41, 20);
    addButton("8", output, 50, 50, 41, 20);
    addButton("9", output, 95, 50, 41, 20);
    addButton("/", command, 140, 50, 41, 20);

    addButton("4", output, 5, 75, 41, 20);
    addButton("5", output, 50, 75, 41, 20);
    addButton("6", output, 95, 75, 41, 20);
    addButton("*", command, 140, 75, 41, 20);

    addButton("1", output, 5, 100, 41, 20);
    addButton("2", output, 50, 100, 41, 20);
    addButton("3", output, 95, 100, 41, 20);
    addButton("-", command, 140, 100, 41, 20);

    addButton("0", output, 5, 125, 41, 20);
    addButton(".", output, 50, 125, 41, 20);
    addButton("=", command, 95, 125, 41, 20);
    addButton("+", command, 140, 125, 41, 20);

    addButton("с", command, 5, 150, 85, 20);
    addButton("<", command, 95, 150, 85, 20);

    addButton("sqrt", command, 5, 175, 85, 20);
    addButton("pow(x,2)", command, 95, 175, 85, 20);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    TextEvent t = new TextEvent(getContentPane(), 1);
}

private class OutputAction implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String input = event.getActionCommand();
        if (start) {
            display.setText("");
            start = false;
        }
        display.setText(display.getText() + input);
    }
}

private class CommandAction implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (start) {
            if (command.equals("-")) {
                display.setText(command);
                start = false;
            } else {
                lastCom = command;
            }
        }else if (command.equals("sqrt")) {
            display.setText("" + Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
            start = true;
        } else if (command.equals("pow(x,2)")) {
            display.setText("" + Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()), 2));
            start = true;
        }else if (command.equals("с")) {
            display.setText("");
            start = true;
        }else if (command.equals("<")) {
            //???
        } else {
            calculate(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            lastCom = command;
            start = true;
        }
    }
}

public void calculate(double x) {
    if (lastCom.equals("+")) {
        result += x;
        display.setText("" + result);
    } else if (lastCom.equals("-")) {
        result -= x;
        display.setText("" + result);
    } else if (lastCom.equals("*")) {
        result *= x;
        display.setText("" + result);
    } else if (lastCom.equals("/")) {
        if (x == 0) {
            display.setText("Деление на ноль");
        } else {
            result /= x;
            display.setText("" + result);
        }
    } else if (lastCom.equals("=")) {
        result = x;
        display.setText("" + result);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyCalc();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не работают, похоже, потому что присваивается start = true, а потом работает только ветка `if (start) { if (command.equals("-")) ...  }`, (дальше стоит else).

И бинарные операции, вроде, не должны работать. Потому что сначала надо сохранить куда-то текущее значение, потом запомнить операцию и только по = её вычислить. А не наоборот.

А ещё, по-моему, есть проблема с передачей текущего значения result в `public void calculate(double x)`.